# Polymer content issue for ie11

Tags: javascript, polymer, internet-explorer-11, polymer-1.0

I am using polymer 1.
I have used something like this in polymer and I am passing the section's content from the point where i use this component.
It's working fine for chrome and firefox.
But for IE-11, I am not getting anything for the content.

```
<section id="asdf" class="className">
    <content select="section"></content>
</section>
```

Does someone know the about this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `select` attribute value to contain a period. The `select` attribute needs a selector not a string.

```
<template>
  <header>Local dom header followed by distributed dom.</header>
  <content select=".content"></content>
  <footer>Footer after distributed dom.</footer>
</template>
```

[Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution)